# How to handle alert on firefox 10

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: Page-1 Screenshot]I m using firefox 10 and selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar . I am writing script using webdriver only. In my application there is one alert box with OK button. I try many code solution but does not work. Following are workarounds that i tried

Solution 1:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(msg){};");
```

Solution 2:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

[image: page 2 screenshot]
But It displays below error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I use the second solution and it works. Are you sure there is only one dialog present there?

Comment: You are right . Actually scenario is like that. When my page loads it displays Ajax control (Progress bar) and after some second it displays alert box. Once script clicks on OK button and it go back to parent page. It displays error. Please help me... I am blocked. I am attached page 1 and page 2 screenshot.. if you can guide me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you the following solutions :

- If the code says that there is still another dialog after you click ok on the first one, try to do one more time : `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss()`;
- Check default wait timing for elements to appear (it should be at least `1 second`)
- If does not work, try to handle this part of this code within a try-catch, catching `UnhandledAlertException` exception and try to `dismiss()` in the catch code.
- It is the first time you have problems with this version of Firefox? I am using Firefox 13.0.1 because I had lots of problems with other versions, maybe you should reconsider an upgrade.

Tell me if something was useful for you

Comment: Thanks you loan.... it works now for me... i updgrade browser version and it starts working.. Again thank for your help..

Comment: No problem. If this helped you to solve the problem, you can accept the answer. Good luck!